# Telerik RadGrid Group Expand Shows Invisible Data

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

1. Using telerik radgrid control I have developed a table where data is shown in groups in asp.net. The groups can be collapsed and expanded. In the code behind, I have made an item (a row) invisible. But, the item becomes visible when I collapse the group and then expand it. How to solve that?
2. How to track the invisible item (a row) in code behind?
3. If no item (a row) is there in a group, how to invisible the group?
4. If the group is invisible, how to track the invisible group in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a boolean variable in your code behind. Then data-bind the visible attribute to the variable(data-bind="visible: variableName"). When you want the table visible just set your variable to true.